# Set padding to nested React Native Text component not working in Android

Tags: react-native

What I want to is set padding to nested `<Text>`in React Native, it's working in web based react-native, but Android device or emulator it doesn't work properly. Below is what I desired to.

[image]

---

But, like below capture, in Android device or emulator, You can see `info` 's padding is not affected. How do I do that propery?

[image]

---

https://snack.expo.io/HJBd!h2l8

The code is simple.

```
 <Text>
   <Text style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Info</Text> What I want to is simple.
 </Text>
```

Comment: `<Text>` component does not use flexbox layout anymore, so the margin and padding wouldn't work. You have to wrap you <Text> inside <View> and add the padding.

Comment: you have to use responsive styling in your app just search for :-  responsive style react native and check how to give size in dp insted of px

Answer (score 8):

Because padding inside `<Text>` component in react-native is not supported, your desire approach is slightly tricky and may cause some unwanted layout. You can use the following sample code to see the problem of this approach without some complex ways like passing Props or create your own components, etc.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: "column", paddingTop:50}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
          <Text style={{ padding:10, fontSize: 11, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Info</Text>
          <Text style={{paddingTop:10}}>This line need to set padding too</Text>
          <Text>Below long long long long long long long long text</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{paddingTop: 20, flexDirection:'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
          <Text style={{ padding:10, fontSize: 11, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Info</Text>
          <Text style={{paddingTop:10}}>what happen if the line is too long long long long long long long </Text>
          <Text>Below long long long long long long long long text</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Update: the dirty and bad way. Use `lineHeight` is simulating `padding top and bottom`, add `whitespace` to create `padding left and right`.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingTop: 60 }}>

      <Text>
      <Text style={ style.TextHightlight }>    Info    </Text> What I want to is simple. if longlon g longlong longlongl  onglonglong longlonglonglo nglonglonglonglongl ongtext
       </Text> 

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    TextHightlight: {
    fontSize:11,
    lineHeight: 11+11+10,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  },
});
```

This is a static example.

For dynamic fontSize. You want to create something like `const DYN_FSIZE = 10`; Then `fontSize: DYN_FONTSIZE` and `lineHeight: DYN_FSIZE*3`.

Same idea apply to the whitespace, create your own `addWhiteSpace` function.

Comment: Actually what I want to `info` and long text line should be located same line, your way will make another line when text is long, maybe I questioned with insufficient information - sorry.

Comment: @Juntae, what you want to achieve is currently impossible for RN on mobile. The only hack way I can come up is to "manually" do that, which I highly unrecommend, see my update you can get the idea.

Comment: Defining `lineHeight` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered the same problem recently and what I did is that I did not put the Text component inside another text component, but put it inside a View Component. I believe you have done former case because you want something like span effect of HTML in react native.
So making the outside element View does the trick. For View Component you can add the following style,

```
flexDirection : "row",
justifyContent : "flex-end",
```

and Now the Text Component works. I belive that this is what you were looking for.